# jQuery: confirm if .html() is addable

Tags: javascript, jquery

To save up on performance, I load social links by adding them when user hovers over the follow/like buttons. Example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.trigger').bind('click mouseover', function(){

        jQuery(this).html('<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script><a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="medium"> Follow @twitter </a>');

        jQuery('.trigger').unbind('click mouseover');

    });

});
```

Works fine. In fact, you should do this as well.

The problem is that in Firefox when you use incognito mode, it blocks social links, so .html() doesn't output anything.

The same problem with some browser add-ons that blocks social links.

Is there anyway to find out if `.html()` did output the code, **and if not**, just add a link like:

```
jQuery(this).html('<a href="">Follow</a>');
```

Comment: `.html() doesn't output anything` - `undefined`, empty string, null?

Comment: @Justinas What do you mean? Just try the code here: http://the-artifice.com -- hover your cursor over the social links on the side-bar. Note that services as jsFiddle doesn't seem to allow .html() parsing....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the script yourself rather than this way and then check if it succeeded:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.trigger').one('click mouseover', function(){

        // we add just the HTML manually
        $(this).html('<a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="medium"> Follow @twitter </a>');
        // and the script with jQuery
        $.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js").fail(function(err) { 
            // react to errors here, for example set the .html
        }).done(function(success) { 
            // here we can be sure the script loaded.
        });
    });

});
```

Note that a particularly clever ad blocker *could* intercept the request and return an empty response instead of a 404 - but in practice none do.

I also generally disagree with your assertion that they should be lazy loaded - in general it's mostly fine to just add the word `async` to the script and it won't block the page loading and load later:

```
<!--- NOTE THE 'async' ---> 
<script async src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="medium"> Follow @twitter </a>
```

> `async` - Set this Boolean attribute to indicate that the browser should, if possible, execute the script asynchronously. It has no effect on inline scripts (i.e., scripts that don't have the src attribute).

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

---

As general code review, `ready` takes a parameter which you can use to short name jQuery (as $ commonly), you should use the standard`.on` in favor of the deprecated  deprecated  `.bind` (and `.off` for unbind).

---

Update, I already realized that what you were doing with the `bind/unbind` (`on/off`) pair is essentially a `one` which fires an event only once on the first time - so I changed it to that.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this. For completion, can you please update my code with your `.on` and `.off` suggestion? I'm going to test it regardless and report back.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson if you would like I can make a short jsfiddle illustrating this works (or even a stack snippets). It appears that another user has already updated the answer for me (thanks redbmk) but as you can see for the non-delegating syntax (the regular syntax) it's just changing the name,.

Comment: Works great! Glad to learn from you! One question. I load Facebook button like this: `jQuery(this).html('<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2Fusername&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=235&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=58" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: medium none;height: 45px;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;overflow: hidden;position: absolute;width: 160px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');` and it gets blocked too. Any way to implement this approach here too?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson in general? No, iFrames have the same origin policy which means the outer page can't know anything about the inner one without permission. You could make a direct `$.getScript` HTTP request to a facebook ad element (for example, a Facebook Pixel source) and just check if _that_ loaded. Or - if the twitter one failed then assume the FB one won't work either.

Comment: Thanks again for everything, this is exactly what I was looking for. Although all things considered, I may go with the `async` as I was only introduced to this approach via your answer.

Comment: This is probably what I would do as well. Happy coding. You might want to also consider `defer` in favor of `async` if it's not something users will do when the page loads, see http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html about the difference.